# How to put special chars in a string after pipe in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm migrating some SAS software from a server Unix to a server Linux.

Currently, in a SAS program, I have the following instruction:

```
Filename myname pipe "ls -le &mypath." ;
```

(then the file `myname` is used in a `data` step as `InFile myname truncover end=fine;`).

The option `-e`, in the `ls` of Unix, produces a list of files where the year is always printed, even for the recently created files.

For example, compare:

```
myserver.myuser:/mypath> ls -l myfile
-rwxr-xr-x   1 auser   auser   24422893965 Nov  5 06:17 myfile
```

with:

```
myserver.myuser:/mypath> ls -le myfile
-rwxr-xr-x   1 auser   auser   24422893965 Nov  5 06:17:27 2021 myfile
```

In Linux, the option `-e` of `ls` does not exist, but you can have the same result with the command:

```
ls -l --time-style="+%b %d %T %Y"
```

The problem is how to use this command, which contains special characters like `“` and `%`, in the SAS instruction.

I tried with :

```
Filename itt pipe "ls -l --time-style='+%%b %%d %%T %%Y' &mypath." ;
```

but I get:

```
total 1420
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser mygroup 1450000 052130864ov %d %T %Y myfile
```

I tried:

```
Filename itt pipe "ls -l --time-style='+%str(%)b %str(%)d %str(%)T %str(%)Y' &mypath." ;
```

but I get

```
total 1420
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myuser mygroup 1450000 )b )d )T )Y myfile
```

Is there a way to make that command work?

Any alternative solution to get the same result is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%nrstr`. This will not resolve `%` signs at compilation time.

```
Filename itt pipe "ls -l --time-style='%nrstr(+%b %d %T %Y)' &mypath.";
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to deal with strings that include macro trigger characters, `&` and `%`, in SAS code than it is in macro code.

If you really want to define the fileref MYNAME you could use the FILENAME() function call in a data step.  Or use the QUOTE() function to generate a macro variable that has single quotes on the outside to protect the macro triggers that you could then use in your FILENAME statement.

```
data _null_;
  length cmd $300;
  cmd = catx(' ','ls -l --time-style="+%b %d %T %Y"',"&mypath");
  call symputx('lscmd',quote(trim(cmd),"'"));
run;
filename myname pipe &lscmd;
```

But why not just build the ls command as part of the data step that reads the results?  You could also use a style for the datetime value that is easier for SAS to read, such as something the DATETIME informat understands.

```
data ls_output;
  length cmd $300;
  cmd = catx(' ','ls -l --time-style="+%d%b%Y:%T"',"&mypath");
  infile lscmd pipe filevar=cmd truncover ;
  input mode :$11. links owner :$20. group :$20. size lastmod :datetime. file $256.;
  format lastmod datetime19.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! The program is not mine, it is an inheritance of an inheritance. It was written by what in Italy we call UCAF, Ufficio Complicazione Affari Semplici = Office for complicating simple business.

Comment: Sorry for having given the tick to the other answer, but since both are perfect, in these cases I usually give the tick to the user with lower reputation.

Comment: Well shucks, I feel like I gotta give a Tom a tick as well

Comment: @StuSztukowski Well deserved. Both solutions are perfectly working.